# Index in ScrewTurn Wiki

Tags: indexing, screwturn

I have created multiple pages using ScrewTurn Wiki and now would like to build an index page. Could anyone please tell me how to create an index page in ScrewTurn Wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are really looking for in an "index" page, there are several things you can do.

1. Assuming your wiki site is http://somedomain.com/wiki, you can view all pages at http://somedomain.com/wiki/allpages.aspx.
2. If you assign categories to your wiki pages (which you should do), then you can view all categories at http://somedomain.com/wiki/category.aspx.
3. Modify your "home" page using wiki markup to display different options for displaying page content.  See http://web.archive.org/web/20120822144157/http://www.screwturn.eu/Help.WikiMarkup.ashx for examples.
4. Display the category tag cloud using wiki markup: {Cloud}

If you have specific listing you would like, be a little more specific and maybe can suggest more options.